# PDF Named Dictionary Modification

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am manually modifying a PDF by hand and need to make an update to the Names Dictionary.  There is an object similar to following that encodes what I believe to be the filename of embedded document:

```
25 0 obj
<</Names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
endobj
```

What type of encoding is this?:

```
<FEFF003C00320030003E0061002E006A00700067>26 0 R
```

I was able to get a peek at what the hash above using pdftk:

```
(þÿ^@<^@2^@0^@>^@a^@.^@j^@p^@g) 26 0 R
```

I can see that this visually represents something like: (<20>a.jpg) 26 0 R - Which does cdorrespond to ojbect 26

I would like to be able to de-crypt/de-compress this object, modify it by hand, and then add it back to the PDF (or something similar and modify the xref tables etc).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call "hash" is a Base64 encoded string in UTF-16BE encoding.

Generally you should never modify a PDF by hand as it is a binary file format.